# Jquery wont change text in div on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to have text appear in a `<div>` when you hover over an `<li>` in a different `<div>` For some reason its not working. It should take the `data-name` from the `<li>` and pass it to `.pagename_h1` using `html()`...heres the code:

**list item**
`<li id="navIcon" data-name="News"><a class='inline' href="#inline_content"><img src="images/christian.jpg" class="hoverImages"></a></li>`

**list item**
`<script>$('.navIcon').hover(
      function () {
        $('.pagename_h1').html($(this).attr('data-name'));
});
  </script>`

**the div where the data-name should show up in text**
`<section class="round">
     <div class="pagename_h1"> </div>
                   </section>`

Am i using the CSS selector correctly for `.pagename_h1`? Should I be using something other than hover instead? Is `.html()` not the proper function to replace text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navIcon is an ID not a class.

Change it to `$('#navIcon').hover()`

Read more about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), specifically [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: awesome! thanks i tried adding a few more list items with the same `id name` but with a different `data-name` but it only works on the very first one. any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Then it should be a class. You can have multiple elements with the same class but only one with that ID. So your JS is right, change your HTML to be `class="navIcon"`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve an element with class = navIcon while you set that navIcon as an id . Try the following selector instead :

```
$('#navIcon')
```